# Get values from a DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with only 1 row in pandas.

The row has a index/name as a date.

I want to retrieve this date and the value in the 4th column.

I can get the value of the 4th column in this single row by using

```
first_row = data.iloc[0]
value = row[3]
```

but how can I get the corresponding date in this row?

I have tried `first_row.index` but it wont work. If I use `data.index` I get a DatetimeIndex with only one element but wouldn't it be better code if I could retrieve the index directly from the row?

Comment: Sorry are you after just `df.index[0]` in this case? In the general case if you are using integer indexing then using the integer to index into the index will return the index value, additionally in your example you can access the index value using `first_row.name`

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 choices, if you are performing integer indexing into the df, then using the same integer to index into the index will return that value.

If you have selected a specific row then you can access the index value by using the `.name` attribute.

Example:

```
In [3]:
import io
import pandas as pd    
t="""date,value
2014/01/05,1515    
2014/02/05,15
2014/05/05,1"""
df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])    
df

Out[3]:

            value
date             
2014-01-05   1515
2014-02-05     15
2014-05-05      1

In [7]:
df.index[1]

Out[7]:    
Timestamp('2014-02-05 00:00:00')

In [16]:
df.iloc[1].name

Out[16]    
Timestamp('2014-02-05 00:00:00')
```